# Why does the BERT NSP head linear layer have two outputs?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, transformer-model, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Here's the code in question.

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L491

```
class BertOnlyNSPHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_relationship = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, 2)

    def forward(self, pooled_output):
        seq_relationship_score = self.seq_relationship(pooled_output)
        return seq_relationship_score
```

I think it was just ranking how likely one sentence would follow another? Wouldn't it be one score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two scores are meant to represent unnormalized probabilities (`logits`) from the model. If we softmax them, we get our predictions, where index 0 indicates next sentence, and index 1 indicates random.

This is just a stylistic choice on the HuggingFace author's behalf, probably to keep the loss function consistent.

Here's the `forward` method of `BertForPretraining`, where `self.cls` is `BertOnlyNSPHead`:

```
    prediction_scores, seq_relationship_score = self.cls(sequence_output, pooled_output)

    outputs = (prediction_scores, seq_relationship_score,) + outputs[
        2:
    ]  # add hidden states and attention if they are here

    if masked_lm_labels is not None and next_sentence_label is not None:
        loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
        masked_lm_loss = loss_fct(prediction_scores.view(-1, self.config.vocab_size), masked_lm_labels.view(-1))
        next_sentence_loss = loss_fct(seq_relationship_score.view(-1, 2), next_sentence_label.view(-1))
        total_loss = masked_lm_loss + next_sentence_loss
        outputs = (total_loss,) + outputs
```

it's convenient to use the same CrossEntropyLoss for both MLM and NSP.

As you describe, it would be equivalent to have NSP produce a single output, then feed that number through a sigmoid to get probability of the next sentence. We can then train with `BCEWithLogitsLoss`. (where `BCE` is just the special binary case of cross entropy loss).